# Reading SOAP with Zeep

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I'm trying to read this Soap API 'https://www.shab.ch/soapserver' using Python's [Zeep](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zeep).

```
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from zeep import Client

from zeep.transports import Transport
session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('MYUSERNAME', 'MYPASSWORD')
client = Client('https://www.shab.ch/shabforms/acmsservice?wsdl',
    transport=Transport(session=session))
```

But get the following error message:

```
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: 
https://www.shab.ch/shabforms/acmsservice?wsdl
```

Can anybody see what I am doing wrongly here?

Comment: this endpoint not exists anymore. i suggest to delete the question

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that Python is your problem. Instead you have a rights issue for the WSDL file. A quick Googling turned up:

https://www.shab.ch/soapserver
https://www.shab.ch/shabforms/soapserver?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to go to that part of the Shab.ch server. You need a username and password. Contact: info@sogc.ch